# Is there a more beautiful solution in this case?

Tags: javascript

When you hover the mouse on the block tab, the color of all three blocks changed. Demo https://jsfiddle.net/nf3q223z/

```
document.getElementById('tab').onmouseover=function (e) {
  document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.color = 'red';
}
```

My solution is this: https://jsfiddle.net/nf3q223z/1/

```
document.getElementById('tab').onmouseover=function (e) {
  if(e.target.id != 'tab'){
    document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

It works. Is this a correct, correct way? Or is there a more beautiful solution?

Comment: Your question is asking for opinion and will be closed. In addition, you are required to post a minimal representation of the problem code here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more beautiful solution is to use `hover` pseudo element in CSS, like this: `element:hover {styles here}`. It's pretty good for your simple case.

```css
#tab{
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.my{
    font-size: 160%;
}

.my:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">
  <div class="my" id="sh1">one</div>
  <div class="my" id="sh2">two</div>
  <div class="my" id="sh3">three</div>
</div>
<br><div id="test1"></div>
<br><div id="test2"></div>
<br><div id="test3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'hover' property in CSS.

```
div:hover{
  color: #FF0000;
}
```